# How to Initialize Generic in the Declaration itself?

Tags: c#, asp.net

- Declaration:

  ```
  var list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
  ```
- Assignment:

  ```
  list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "Cat"));
  list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "Dog"));
  list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(4, "Rabbit"));
  ```

How can I initialize the above generic list in the first line itself

for example:

```
List<string> nameslist = new List<string>();
nameslist.Add("one");
nameslist.Add("two"); 
nameslist.Add("three");
```

We can initialize the above in the same line itself:

```
var list = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three" };
```

I want to do the same for my generic list.Any help will be greatly appreciated.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How to: Initialize a Dictionary with a Collection Initializer (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx):

> A `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` contains a collection of key/value pairs. Its Add method takes two parameters, one for the key and one for the value. To initialize a Dictionary, or any collection whose Add method takes multiple parameters, enclose each set of parameters in braces as shown in the following example.

Since a `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>()`'s `Add()` method only accepts *one* parameter, a `KeyValuePair<int, string>`, you'll have to instantiate that object somehow.

A `Dictionary<int, string>`'s `Add()` method on the other hand has two parameters, so you can wrap those parameters in braces **`{ }`**, resulting in this pretty clean code:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    { 1, "Cat" },
    { 2, "Dog" },
    { 4, "Rabbit" },
};
```

This of course doesn't match your declaration of `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>()`, but if you're sure you need that, you can just call `ToList()` on the dictionary to get that.

Alternatively you can change your declaration from `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>()` to `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>>()`, as both types (`List` and `Dictionary`) can be assigned to that.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, use this:

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "Cat"),
    new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "Dog"),
    new KeyValuePair<int, string>(4, "Rabbit")
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call `ToList` at the end of Dictionary initialization:

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> list = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    {1, "Cat"},
    {2, "Dog"},
    {4, "Rabbit"}
}.ToList();
```

notes: feel free to use `var` instead of type declaration for `list` variable. If you can use other types for `list` variables, like `Dictionary<int, string>` or `ICollection<KeyValuePair<int, string>>` - use them and you can get rid of `ToList` call.

Comment: This seems like it is introducing some needless overhead.

Comment: @emodendroket is it really needless? Do you care so much about performance, so that you would neglect readability? OP doesn't state anything about performance requirements.

Comment: As a general rule no, but I think this version is the same or marginally harder to read.  It seems like all you're saving is keystrokes.

Comment: @emodendroket Does it **read** harder, than using lots of ceremony to initialize that list?

Comment: Well, obviously you disagree.  I wouldn't use this method, personally.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Dictionary` instead of a list of `KeyValuePairs`.  If you want to continue to use a list of `KeyValuePairs` I recommend making a convenient `Create` extension method for `KeyValuePair`like [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.create%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has.

Dictionary method:

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, int>
    {
        {"key", 1}
    };
```

List of KeyValuePairs method:

```
public static class KeyValuePair
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a KeyValuePair without having to specify the type arguments. This is similar to Tuple.Create
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the key</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TValue">The type of the value</typeparam>
    /// <param name="key">Value of the key</param>
    /// <param name="value">Value of the value</param>
    /// <returns>KeyValuePair with your specified values</returns>
    public static KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> Create<TKey, TValue>(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value);
    }
}

var myList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>
    {
        //You can use either the extension method or the constructor
        //to initialize the list.  I think the extension method is a bit
        //neater.
        KeyValuePair.Create("key", 1),
        new KeyValuePair<string, int>("keytwo", 2)
    };
```